# DirContextOperations is null

Tags: grails, spring-security, ldap

So I have an application that works perfectly on my desktop, and also works perfectly when deployed to tomcat on a windows machine. However, when I attempt to use this application while deployed on the same version of tomcat, but on AIX, it fails to retrieve data out of LDAP.

A user is able to successfully authenticate, but the context is null. `DirContextOperations` is passed into my `ContextMapper` as null. Does anyone know what ports that need to be open to get this data or what other configuration may need to be done? Based on what I am seeing it has to be a server configuration issue somewhere.

Comment: I am trying the solution that you posted on my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287601/how-to-integrate-an-ldap-user-with-the-person-table-created-by-spring-security-i and I am running into the same issue. Have you found a solution?

Comment: I ran the same code on a windows machine (vs AIX) on a different subnet of the network and it worked. I assumed it was a network issue.

Comment: @JamesKleeh Are you using [Spring Security LDAP](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-ldap) plugin?

Comment: Yes, see Viriato's comment for my complete setup

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Spring Security LDAP](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-ldap/docs/manual/guide/2.%20Usage.html) plugin then it will be easy to co-relate the below mentioned configuration in AIX with the app. I prepared few snapshots for the configuration so that I do not clutter the answer space here. Have a look at [LDAP config in AIX](http://www.slideshare.net/dhiraj.mahapatro/ldap-config-in-aix) and try to setup the same in AIX Server.

Now coming to the LDAP plugin, there is nothing much other than setting up a bunch of properties is required. Values for these properties will be available once the LDAP configuration is done in AIX (as mentioned in the above mentioned slide).

**Note:-**
After creating a standalone LDAP, you might need to add realm if the user is associated to a group. I have not mentioned the same in the slides since I do not have an active LDAP host available now.

**UPDATE**
Instead of using `BindAuthenticator` can you try switching to `PasswordComparisonAuthenticator` for authentication.
Using the below setting in Config forces to use `PasswordComparisonAuthenticator` to authenticate and return back the `DirContextOperations`. Can this setting be tried?

`grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authenticator.useBind = false`

@Refer [LdapAuthentication Implementations](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ldap.html).

Comment: I'm connecting to an existing LDAP server that I have no control over. The configuration I'm using works elsewhere. It doesn't work when it is deployed to a Tomcat server that resides on an AIX OS that is also on a different subnet on our network.

Comment: Got it. I assumed it is deployed to WAS in AIX. Thanks for clarifying, will see if I can help in anyways. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will be the answer in your case. I was also getting **null** in **DirContextOperations** object when trying to obtain values from Active Directory.

I was trying to get ldap attributes like this as the [Grails LDAP plugin Documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-ldap/docs/manual/guide/2.%20Usage.html) states:

```
String mail = ctx.originalAttrs.attrs['mail'].values[0]
```

and all those were null. So I have changed the line above for this one instead and it works for me:

```
String mail = ctx.attributes.getAt('mail').values[0].toString()
```