# How to integrate an LDAP user with the PERSON table created by Spring Security in Grails?

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap

We are creating a grails aplication where we want the user to log in using their Active Directory credentials. Additionally, we want to give the business owner of this application the ability to control who has access to certain links (actions). Because of this we are using the following plugins in our grails application:

1. Spring Security Core
2. Spring Security LDAP
3. Spring Security UI

Because we want to empower the business user to create customized roles with certain permissions(actions) on the fly when necessary, we think that the best Spring Security Configuration is the **Requestmap database based approach**

So far we have accomplished as follows:

- We are being able to authenticate against Active Directory successfully.
- We have also been able to create different Request Mappings for different roles (ROLE_XXX) through the UI interface of the spring-security-ui plugin

**Problems/Questions**

The spring-security-core plugin created the following tables:

- PERSON
- AUTHORITY
- PERSON_AUTHORITY
- REQUESTMAP

These are the tables that support the creation of Roles, the assignment of URLs to roles. However, the Person_Authoritity table as the convention name implies it's a many to many relationship between a PERSON and an AUTHORITY (ROLE) since a person can potentially have more than one role. My problem is that I do not have a Person because the person already exists in Active Directory (an external source) and it was not created in the application.

Is there a way to make the authenticated user to be the PERSON ? The spring security solution requires that Person row or object however you prefer to refer to it.

I have also posted the question here:

http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Issues-integrating-LDAP-Authentication-with-Requestmap-to-Secure-URLs-td4644040.html

Thanks,

Comment: Here is what we had done. We had a similar situation like this where the user was being authenticated against LDAP, what we ended up doing was that once a person is authenticated against LDAP, we used to find him in the Persons table and if he doesn't exist, we would create him there with some basic information and then add that object to the RequestMap. If that person already existed in the Persons table then we don't add him but the key part was that in both the cases the user is still being authenticated against LDAP.

Comment: @allthenutsandbolts Tried it with no success. The password field is a required field, how to pass the j_password field to the user/save action that creates a person? When posting the login to j_security_check I dont have access to the credentials anymore to insert a person record. I tried to create a user in the person table manually via the Spring-security-ui while still authenticating through LDAP but when I went to a secured url it did not work, Seems like there is a disconnect between the user in the person table and the user in LDAP, or maybe something is not registered or initialized.

Comment: You can set that password to anything you want. You won't be using it for authentication. You are right, you don't have access to the j_password field.

Comment: Yes, I understand but let's put this scenario: say that my LDAP user is called "test", I go in an create a record with "test" username in the person table via the spring-security-ui with the role ROLE_USER, additionally I secure a url (admin/addCourse) to the role ROLE_ADMIN. When I log in under "test" if I go to the url admin/addCourse **it allows me**. So it seems like something needs to be called that links the "test" LDAP user with the "test" person record to prevent the "test" user with role ROLE_USER to access the secure url available only under ROLE_ADMIN. Do you know what I mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you need to essentially map the AD user to a Person.

Here are the 3 classes you need in src/groovy. Obviously modify them as needed:

```
    package yourpackagename

    import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GrailsUser
    import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority

    class CustomUserDetails extends GrailsUser{
        final String firstName
        final String lastName

        CustomUserDetails(String username, String password, boolean enabled,
                          boolean accountNonExpired, boolean credentialsNonExpired,
                          boolean accountNonLocked,
                          Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities,
                          long id, String firstName, String lastName) {
            super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired,
                    credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities, id)

            this.firstName = firstName
            this.lastName = lastName
        }
    }

package yourpackagenamehere

import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GrailsUserDetailsService
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.GrantedAuthorityImpl
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils

class CustomUserDetailsService implements GrailsUserDetailsService {

    /**
     * Some Spring Security classes (e.g. RoleHierarchyVoter) expect at least one role, so
     * we give a user with no granted roles this one which gets past that restriction but
     * doesn't grant anything.
     */
    static final List NO_ROLES = [new GrantedAuthorityImpl(SpringSecurityUtils.NO_ROLE)]

    UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username, boolean loadRoles)
    throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return loadUserByUsername(username)
    }

    UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User.withTransaction { status ->

            User user = User.findByUsername(username)
            if (!user) throw new UsernameNotFoundException('User not found', username)

            def authorities = user.authorities.collect {new GrantedAuthorityImpl(it.authority)}

            return new CustomUserDetails(user.username, user.password, user.enabled,
                    !user.accountExpired, !user.passwordExpired,
                    !user.accountLocked, authorities ?: NO_ROLES, user.id,
                    user.firstName, user.lastName)
        } as UserDetails
    }
}

package yourpackagenamehere

import groovy.sql.Sql

import org.springframework.ldap.core.DirContextAdapter
import org.springframework.ldap.core.DirContextOperations
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails
import org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.UserDetailsContextMapper
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.GrantedAuthorityImpl
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils

import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException
import org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException

class CustomUserDetailsContextMapper implements UserDetailsContextMapper {

    private static final List NO_ROLES = [new GrantedAuthorityImpl(SpringSecurityUtils.NO_ROLE)]

    def dataSource

    @Override
    public CustomUserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username, Collection<GrantedAuthority> authority) {

        username = username.toLowerCase()

        User user = User.findByUsername(username)

        String firstName = ctx.originalAttrs.attrs['givenname'].values[0]
        String lastName = ctx.originalAttrs.attrs['sn'].values[0]


        def roles

        User.withTransaction {

            if(!user){
                user = new User(username: username, enabled: true, firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName)
                user.save(flush: true)
            }
            else {
                user = User.findByUsername(username)
                user.firstName = firstName
                user.lastName = lastName
                user.save(flush: true)
            }

            roles = user.getAuthorities()
        }

        if ( !user.enabled )
            throw new DisabledException("User is disabled", username)


        def authorities = roles.collect { new GrantedAuthorityImpl(it.authority) }
        authorities.addAll(authority)
        def userDetails = new CustomUserDetails(username, user.password, user.enabled, false, false, false, authorities, user.id, user.firstName, user.lastName)

        return userDetails
    }

    @Override
    public void mapUserToContext(UserDetails arg0, DirContextAdapter arg1) {
    }
}
```

Under configuration in spring/resources.groovy :

```
import yourpackagenamehere.CustomUserDetailsService
import yourpackagenamehere.CustomUserDetailsContextMapper
beans = {
    userDetailsService(CustomUserDetailsService)

    ldapUserDetailsMapper(CustomUserDetailsContextMapper) {
        dataSource = ref("dataSource")
    }
}
```

Under Config.groovy, here are my settings:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerDn = 'CN=username,OU=People,DC=foo,DC=com'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerPassword = 'password'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.server = 'ldap://foo.com:389/'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.ignorePartialResultException = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.base = 'ou=People,dc=foo,dc=com'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.filter="sAMAccountName={0}"
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.searchSubtree = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.auth.hideUserNotFoundExceptions = false
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.attributesToReturn = null
grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerNames = ['ldapAuthProvider', 'anonymousAuthenticationProvider']
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.mapper.userDetailsClass = 'CustomUserDetails'

grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.retrieveGroupRoles = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.retrieveDatabaseRoles = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.groupSearchBase ='dc=foo,dc=com'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.groupSearchFilter = 'member={0}'
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I will try to make it work upon your suggestion and let you know.

Comment: thank you very much it worked!!! After reading the documentation http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-ldap/docs/manual/guide/2.%20Usage.html it was not obvious to me that overriding those two classes would do the trick. I also had to make the password nullable:true and blank:true on the domain class as well as make sure that it was nullable 'Y' on the database side. I am having an issue with the DirContextOperations object always being null when I run the app. Not sure what it is, but I can live with it for now.

Comment: You know what, I've had that error before! It failed when it was being run on AIX, however worked on Windows. The 2 machines are on different subnets and I chalked it up to a network thing. Please let me know if you figure it out!!!!!!!!