# Grails TransientObjectException

Tags: spring, grails, ldap

This is related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335251/grails-spring-security-ldap), where you will find much of my config.  A ldap user is mapped to the database user table and the entry is created fine.  Then userDetails tries to get the authorities from the main user class resulting in the following exception:

```
2014-01-31 12:10:52,076 [http-bio-8111-exec-4] ERROR [/step].[default]  - Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/step] threw exception
Message: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: packagae.User; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: package.User
    Line | Method
->>  102 | doCall                in org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi$_methodMissing_closure2
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     42 | getAuthorities        in package.User
|     27 | getAuthorities . . .  in package.MdtUserDetails
|     72 | attemptAuthentication in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter
|     49 | doFilter . . . . . .  in     ''
|     82 | doFilter              in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|   1145 | runWorker . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run                   in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: package.User
->>  102 | doCall                in org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi$_methodMissing_closure2
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     42 | getAuthorities        in package.User
|     27 | getAuthorities . . .  in package.MdtUserDetails
|     72 | attemptAuthentication in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter
|     49 | doFilter . . . . . .  in     ''
|     82 | doFilter              in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|   1145 | runWorker . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run                   in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Here are is my user details class:

```
import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority
import org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetails

import package.Role
import package.User

class MdtUserDetails extends User implements LdapUserDetails{



    public MdtUserDetails(String fullName, String email, String username, String password, boolean enabled, boolean accountExpired,
        boolean accountLocked, boolean passwordExpired, Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(username: username, password: password, email: email, fullName: fullName, enabled: enabled, accountExpired: accountExpired, accountLocked: accountLocked, passwordExpired: passwordExpired, authorties: authorities)

    }


    @Override 
    public Set<Role> getAuthorities(){
        return super.getAuthorities()
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDn() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


}
```

And User:

```
class User {

    transient springSecurityService

    String username
    String toString() {
        "${username}"
    }
    String password
    String email
    String fullName
    String userOrg
    boolean enabled = true
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired

    static belongsTo = [organization : Organization]
    static hasMany = [reports: Report, invoices: Invoice]

    static mappedBy = [invoices:'lastUpdatedBy', reports: 'lastUpdatedBy']
    static transients = ['springSecurityService']

    static constraints = {
        username blank: false, unique: true
        //have to nullable true the password in order to map mdtUsers to applicaiton roles.
        password nullable: true, blank: true
        email blank: true, nullable: true
        fullName nullable: true, blank: true
        userOrg nullable: true, blank: true
        organization nullable: true, blank: true
    }

    static mapping = {
        table 'step_users'
        password column: '`password`'
    }

    Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
        UserRole.findAllByUser(this).collect { it.role } as Set
    }

    def beforeInsert() {
        encodePassword()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
        }
    }

    protected void encodePassword() {
        password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is related to cascading events or how I should save the session, or how I'm calling the super class in UserDetails?

**EDIT**

Finally figured this out!

in the UserDetails class I was extending my own user class:

```
import package.User

class MdtUserDetails extends User {
```

Instead I needed to extend the springsecurity user class from here :

```
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
```

I believe that was causing my Transient object exception, as the answer suggested you need to have the belongsTo, etc.  I did have those on my classes.

Comment: What column in `User` is `password` mapped to?

Comment: It is just mapped to password.  the user table is mapped to step_users.

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: package.User
```

This message tells you that the `User` object you want to save contains at least one reference to another domain object that isn't saved.

According to your `User` class this unsaved reference could be a `Report` or an `Invoice` object.
You have the following options to solve this issue:

Save reports and invoices manually before adding them to an user

**or**

enable automatic cascading of reports and invoices using

```
static mapping = {
  reports cascade: 'all-delete-orphan'
  reports invoices: 'all-delete-orphan'
}
```

**or**

add a `belongsTo` relationship to `Invoice` and `Report`:

```
static belongsTo = [user: User]
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  I have the belongsTo relationship already.  I tried the cascade: 'all-delete-orphan' to the User's class with no luck.